# Tabbar not showing in ios application

Tags: ios, tabbar

i am making one iOS tabbar application in that i have put 4 different tabs and whenever i click on 1 st tab and load another view after clicking of the first tab. After that when i press back button then tabbar is not displaying .So that i want hint that  how can i show that 
back the tabbar when we move from one tab from another and yes how i can use consistent the tabbar in whole application can you just guys help me on this i am new to iOS development.

here i am put the screen shot ...
here first screen is this one..[image]

when i tap the video button that are first in the view then  another window open 
which are as under and see the tabbar is not there...
[image]

when in video controller there is tabbar is there but i drag and connect to that then tabbar is disabled[image]

Comment: Please make an effort on your english. I realize it's not everyone's native language (it's not even mine), but your explanation is **really** unclear...

Comment: yes I am making one tabbar application in that there is four tab when i press 2nd tab then load the second view controller and when came back then tabbar will disappear.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code or UI images here, because I still can't follow what you're asking.

Comment: above i put scrren shot for that issue...

Comment: here i have put all the my problem in a screen shot above so plz help me on this

Comment: hello guys i have post the images for the isssue so plz can u guys just give me idea that how i can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screen snapshots, do I correctly assume you're attempting to transition to the "Videos" scene by touching the big "Videos" button in the center of the "Home" scene (rather than touching the tab bar button at the bottom of the screen, which I assume works fine)? If that's the case, you need to have your button tell the view controller's tab bar controller that you want to change the index of the tab bar, and it takes care of it for you. You cannot do the transition using a segue (or at least not without a custom segue, which is even more complicated than the procedure I outline below). If you're changing the view some other way (e.g. using a standard segue or using `presentViewController`, `pushViewController` programmatically, etc.), your tab bar can disappear on you.

You later said:

> when in video controller there is tabbar is there but i drag and connect to that then tabbar is disabled

Yes, that's true. You cannot use a segue from one of your big buttons to one of the tabs in your tab bar. (Or technically, if you wanted to use a segue, it would be a *custom segue* which would do something very much like my below code, though perhaps a tad more complicated.) So, rather than using a segue for your big button, you need to write an `IBAction` (connected to the big `Videos` button on the `Home` scene), that tells the tab bar to change its selection:

```
- (IBAction)clickedVideosButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

A couple of comments:

1. My answer was predicated on the assumption that your tab bar works as expected when you tap on the buttons of the tab bar, itself. If you tap the buttons at the bottom of the screen, do you transition to your other views correctly and preserve the tab bar? If so, my answer above should solve your issues in getting the big buttons to work. If not, though, then the problem rests elsewhere and you need to show us your code that might account for that (either you're something non-standard in the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` methods, or your `viewDidLoad` of the view is doing something nonstandard).
2. If I understand your user interface design right, you have the tab bar at the bottom as well as the big buttons in the middle, which presumably do the same thing. That is, no offense, a curious user interface design (duplicative buttons, requiring extra tap on a button, etc.). You might want to choose to either use either big buttons (in which you can retire the tab bar, eliminate the `IBAction` code I've provided above, and just use a nice simple navigation controller and push segues, for example), or just use the tab bar (and lose the home screen, lose the big buttons, etc.).
3. You also made reference to "press back button", and I don't see any "back" button on any of your screen snapshots. Do I infer that you have a navigation controller and you're doing a `pushViewController` or push segue somewhere? If you're doing something with back buttons, you might need to clarify your question further.